# In javascript, should I add functions to object or object prototype

Tags: javascript, oop, javascript-objects

I am building a chess game in javascript right now, and am a little unsure about the correct way to work with inheritance. On one part of the code I have a piece object with different piece types extending it, for example with a knight (as it's the shortest) it looks like this (without the comments):

**pieces**

```
/************* piece ********************/
function Piece(square, color) {
    this.square = square;
    this.color = color;
}

Piece.prototype.get_path = function(to) {
    return null;
};

Piece.prototype.get_capture_path = function(to) {
    return this.get_path(to);
};

Piece.prototype.isAt= function(square) {
  return (this.square.equals(square));
};    

/************* KNIGHT *****************/
Knight.prototype = Object.create(Piece.prototype);
Knight.prototype.constructor = Knight;
function Knight(square, color) {
    Piece.call(this, square, color);

    this.type = KNIGHT;
}

Knight.prototype.get_path = function(to) {
    var h_movement = Math.abs(this.square.file - to.file);
    var v_movement = Math.abs(this.square.rank - to.rank);

    if ((h_movement === 2 && v_movement === 1) || (h_movement === 1 && v_movement === 2)) {
        return [to];
    }
    return null;
};
```

And it works fine, as you would expect the object looks as follow according to chrome's console.log output:

```
Knight {square: Square, color: "w", type: "N"}
color: "w"
square: Square
type: "N"
__proto__: Knight
    constructor: Knight(square, color)
    get_path: (to)
    __proto__: Piece
```

Now in a different file of the code, I have the definition of a square object, which looks like this:

**Square**

```
function Square(file, rank) {
    this.file = file;
    this.rank = rank;

    this.equals = function(other) {
       return (this.file === other.file && this.rank === other.rank);
    };

    this.toString = function() {
        return String(file) + ' ' + String(rank);
    };

    this.getSquareAtOffset = function(file, rank) {
        file = Number(file)? file : 0;
        rank = Number(rank)? rank : 0;
        return new Square(this.file + file, this.rank + rank);
    }
};
```

This also works fine, and, as you would probably expect, the console log of the object is as follow:

```
Square {file: 1, rank: 1}
equals: (other)
file: 1
getSquareAtOffset: (file, rank)
rank: 1
toString: ()
__proto__: Square
```

This also works fine. So my question is, which approach is better at which situation? What is the difference between the two objects apart from one having it's function as a property and the other having it as a property of the prototype?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual preferred or recommended way of writing is as an object:

```
var Square = {};
Square.file = file;
Square.rank = rank;
Square.equals = function(other) {
   return (this.file === other.file && this.rank === other.rank);
};
Square.toString = function() {
    return String(file) + ' ' + String(rank);
};
Square.getSquareAtOffset = function(file, rank) {
    file = Number(file)? file : 0;
    rank = Number(rank)? rank : 0;
    return new Square(this.file + file, this.rank + rank);
};
```

Reference:
http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html

With that said, many top projects use other, and including Prototypical, pattern(s).

Answer (score 1):

Properties added to `prototype` runs once and dont runs later while `creating objects` but `properties` added to `this` runs all the times when you create a `new object`.

When you try to access a `property` `object` first look inside the `properties` added to `this` `object`. If not found on this `object` and then in `prototype` and then `prototype chain` untill parent is reach or property found in between.

Javascript supports prototypal inheritance. So it is good to add the properties in prototype.

Also store the `this` reference inside a local variable

```
function Piece(square, color) {
    var self = this;
    self.square = square;
    self.color = color;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

functions add to  object will be unique to each instance of the object;
functions add to prototype will be the same each instance of the object;
that`s the deference ,choose by your need